# How to release memory of docker after copying files?

Tags: java, docker, volumes, mounted-volumes

We are developing java application where performance is very important. It processes a lot of files and creates a lot of files as output. So to free memory we make temporary save of data to disk after batch of files (e.g. 15 files). These temporary saved files could be loaded by application later if needed.
We are also dockerizing our application and we have a problem. Docker has its own file system. So even after we save files to disk, docker keeps something in memory, that is connecting files inside its own file system with saved files on disk. We use bind-mounts. 
So our java application is able to process thousands of files, but dockerized version slows down after 75 files and it throws out of memory exception after about 150 files.
Is there any way to release memory of docker after copying files?

Comment: Have you tried mounting a volume to hold the files?

Comment: A [mcve] demonstrating the issue would be helpful.  On native Linux there isn't a separate Docker filesystem (just some very magical kernel-level remapping); on MacOS I've basically taken to avoiding bind mounts as much as possible.  If your application is all about bulk local file processing, there might not be a whole lot of advantages to running it in Docker.

Comment: Im developing in WIndows environment and finally we will deploy to AWS S3, so Linux, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks David Maze, running on Linux fixed the problem.